# Elasticsearch Scripts to add element into an array

Tags: scala, groovy, elasticsearch, elastic4s

I am working on ElasticSearch in a scala project. I am using *elastic4s* as the client. I am trying to add elements to a document, from an iterator one by one.

```
while (iterator.hasNext) {
  counter +=1
  client.execute {
    update id reportID in "reports/report" script "ctx._source.elasticData += output" params Map("output" -> iterator.next().toStringifiedJson)
  }.await
}
```

The above code does not work yielding the following error:

```
    [ERROR] [03/06/2015 14:44:23.515] [SparkActorSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5] [akka://SparkActorSystem/user/spark-actor] failed to execute script
    org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException: failed to execute script
        at org.elasticsearch.action.update.UpdateHelper.prepare(UpdateHelper.java:189)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.update.TransportUpdateAction.shardOperation(TransportUpdateAction.java:176)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.update.TransportUpdateAction.shardOperation(TransportUpdateAction.java:170)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.support.single.instance.TransportInstanceSingleOperationAction$AsyncSingleAction$1.run(TransportInstanceSingleOperationAction.java:187)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException: script_lang not supported [groovy]
        at org.elasticsearch.script.ScriptService.dynamicScriptEnabled(ScriptService.java:521)
        at org.elasticsearch.script.ScriptService.verifyDynamicScripting(ScriptService.java:398)
        [ERROR] [03/06/2015 14:44:23.515] [SparkActorSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5] [akka://SparkActorSystem/user/spark-actor] failed to execute script
    org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException: failed to execute script
        at org.elasticsearch.action.update.UpdateHelper.prepare(UpdateHelper.java:189)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.update.TransportUpdateAction.shardOperation(TransportUpdateAction.java:176)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.update.TransportUpdateAction.shardOperation(TransportUpdateAction.java:170)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.support.single.instance.TransportInstanceSingleOperationAction$AsyncSingleAction$1.run(TransportInstanceSingleOperationAction.java:187)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException: script_lang not supported [groovy]
        at org.elasticsearch.script.ScriptService.dynamicScriptEnabled(ScriptService.java:521)
        at org.elasticsearch.script.ScriptService.verifyDynamicScripting(ScriptService.java:398)
        at org.elasticsearch.script.ScriptService.compile(ScriptService.java:363)
        at org.elasticsearch.script.ScriptService.executable(ScriptService.java:503)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.update.UpdateHelper.prepare(UpdateHelper.java:183)
        ... 6 moreat org.elasticsearch.script.ScriptService.compile(ScriptService.java:363)
        at org.elasticsearch.script.ScriptService.executable(ScriptService.java:503)
        at org.elasticsearch.
action.update.UpdateHelper.prepare(UpdateHelper.java:183)
    ... 6 more
```

The problems is with the script I assume but I could not find any solution. Please help...

Comment: Does adding groovy dependency solve the problem? See here: https://gist.github.com/hkorte/6efadb547b55976ae466

Comment: Nope I have tried it @Opal

Comment: Does this help (if using ES prior to 1.4) https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/9422

Comment: What version of es are you using. Things changed from 1.3.x to 1.4.x  what you need to do is make a change to support scripting and potentially groovy but different depending on your version

Comment: The first link by @Opal actually worked this time thank you all.

Comment: @igalbenardete, adding it as answer then, please accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does adding groovy dependency solve the problem? Please see that: [gist](http://gist.github.com/hkorte/6efadb547b55976ae466).

Comment: To be clear, it's not elastic4s that needs the dep, its any Java-based ES client, of which e4s is one.